# Wait for action creator to finish before calling another action creator - Redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, spotify, redux-thunk

i have 2 action creator in my app called createPlaylist and fillPlaylist, in order to call fillPlaylist i have to call createPlaylist first to get the id of the playlist (state.playlistDetail.id in fillPlaylist). the problem is when i called fillPlaylist, createPlaylist is still fetching the data so i can't call fillPlaylist because state.playlistDetail.id is undefined. i want to wait until createPlaylist finished the request then called fillPlaylist, how can i achieve this?

createPlaylist

```
export const createPlaylist = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    let uris = []

    const data =  JSON.stringify({
        'name': 'Playlist Name',
        'description': 'Playlist description',
    })

    const response = await spotify.post(`/users/${state.user.id}/playlists`, data, {
        'headers' : {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + state.token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        
    })

    dispatch({type: 'CREATE_PLAYLIST', payload: response.data})

}
```

fillPlaylist

```
export const fillPlaylist = (uris) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    const data =  JSON.stringify({
        'uris': uris
    })
    console.log('state.playlistDetail', state)
    const response = await spotify.post(`/playlists/${state.playlistDetail.id}/tracks`, data, {
        'headers' : {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + state.token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        
    })

    dispatch({type: 'FILL_PLAYLIST', payload: response.data})
}
```

Result Component (this is where i called createPlaylist and fillPlaylist)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createPlaylist, fillPlaylist } from '../actions'

class Result extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    createPlaylist = () => {
        this.props.createPlaylist()

        let uris = []

        this.props.recommendations.forEach(item => { 
            uris.push(item.uri)
        })

        this.props.fillPlaylist(uris)
    }

    render() {

        return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Result</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.createPlaylist}>Create Playlist</button>
                </div>
            );
        
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {recommendations: state.recommendations};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {createPlaylist, fillPlaylist})(Result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you said you need to await for `createPlaylist` to finish fetching data, so why not merge the 2 functions into one, like this:

```
export const createAndFillPlaylist = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const state = getState();
    let uris = state.recommendations.map(item => item.uri);
    const PlayListBody = JSON.stringify({
      name: "Playlist Name",
      description: "Playlist description"
    });
    const headers = {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + state.token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
    const { data } = await spotify.post(
      `/users/${state.user.id}/playlists`,
      PlayListBody,
      { headers }
    );
    dispatch({ type: "CREATE_PLAYLIST", payload: data });
    const createPlaylistBody = JSON.stringify({
      uris: uris
    });
    const response = await spotify.post(
      `/playlists/${data.id}/tracks`,
      createPlaylistBody,
      {
        headers
      }
    );
    dispatch({ type: "FILL_PLAYLIST", payload: response.data });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

and for the component, no need to `mapStateToProps`. here's the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createAndFillPlayList } from "../actions";

class Result extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Result</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.createAndFillPlayList}>
          Create Playlist
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { createAndFillPlayList }
)(Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using react-redux, have you looked into redux-sagas middleware yet? It's incredibly helpful in managing side-effects like data fetching, kind of acting like a separate thread that can started and stopped, and trigger other actions (sagas) once your data is back.

I've used both redux-thunk and redux-sagas to help with this problem that you're having.

https://redux-saga.js.org/